# Combining Nim Games

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I was reading the Wikipedia article on the [Sprague-Grundy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem#thirdExample), and I can't get through their [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem#Combining_Games) for combining games.

The example combines two sets of three heaps. The first set has 1, 2 and 2 elements in its heaps, and is described by starting position $\color{blue}S$, and the second set has 1, 1 and 1 elements in its heaps, and is described by starting position $\color{red}{S'}$:

$$ \color{blue}{S = \left\{ 
    \left\{ *1, \left\{ *1 \right\}, *2 \right\},
    \left\{ *2, \left\{ *1, \left\{ *1 \right\}, *2 \right\} \right\},
    \left\{ \left\{ *1 \right\}, \left\{ \left\{ *1 \right\} \right\}, \left\{ *1, \left\{ *1 \right\}, *2 \right\} \right\}
\right\}} $$

$$ \color{red}{S' = \left\{ 
    \left\{ *1 \right\}
\right\}} $$

Then the combined game's starting position is said to be:

$$ \color{blue}S + \color{red}{S'} =
    \left\{
        \left\{
            \color{blue}S,
            \color{red}{\left\{ *1 \right\}}
        \right\}
    \right\}
    \cup
    \left\{
        \left\{
            \color{red}{S'},
            \color{blue}{\left\{ *1, \left\{ *1 \right\}, *2 \right\}}
        \right\},
        \left\{
            \color{red}{S'},
            \color{blue}{\left\{ *2, \left\{ *1, \left\{ *1 \right\}, *2 \right\} \right\}}
        \right\},
        \left\{
            \color{red}{S'},
            \color{blue}{\left\{ \left\{ *1 \right\}, \left\{ \left\{ *1 \right\} \right\}, \left\{ *1, \left\{ *1 \right\}, *2 \right\} \right\}}
        \right\}
    \right\}
$$

I can't make sense of the elements of $\color{blue}{S} + \color{red}{S'}$. For example, if I expressed it as the numbers of objects in every heap, what position/positions does $\left\{ \color{blue}S, \color{red}{\left\{ *1 \right\}} \right\} \in \color{blue}{S} + \color{red}{S'}$ represent? Does this addition of sets represent positions that I could express like this at all? It doesn't seem right to me that, if $\color{blue}{S} + \color{red}{S'}$ is the starting position, I could pick $\left\{ \color{blue}S, \color{red}{\left\{ *1 \right\}} \right\}$ as my next position, then $\color{red}{\left\{ *1 \right\}}$, then $\color{red}{*1}$ and finally end the 6-heap game in four moves, that should be impossible.

Comment: What are the legal moves in this game?

Comment: It's just two nim games of 3 piles each combined (i.e. a nim game of 6 piles). I was following the WIkipedia article which defines each position in the game as the set of possible next positions (e.g. no possible moves is the set {}. a position with a single move that leaves no possible next move is {{}}).f

Comment: I'm not a computer right now to type up a correction / full answer, but the basic idea is that Wikipedia's example is wrong since a lot of those commas should be plus signs.

Comment: That explains a lot! Having that I can start to see things make sense. If you'd like to go ahead and type up the answer, I would definitely accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Mark S.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215122/combining-nim-games#comment6617483_3215122) seems like he won't post an answer himself, I'll answer my own question with his correction.

The example is incorrect.

Something that *is* correctly stated in the article is the definition of the operation $+$ used for combining games. We'll say $S$ represents game one and $S'$ represents game two. This operation is *recursively defined* as:

$$ S + S' = \left\{ S + s' \mid s' \in S' \right\} \cup \left\{ s + S' \mid s \in S \right\}$$

Each element of $S + s'$ of $\left\{ S + s' \mid s' \in S' \right\}$ represents having picked $s'$ as the next position in game two, and thus combines this new position of game two with an untouched game one. Therefore, $\left\{ S + s' \mid s' \in S' \right\}$ will be the set of positions that can be reached by making a move in game two. The case for $\left\{ S' + s \mid s \in S \right\}$ is analogous.

The recursive expansion reaches its end with $\left\{\right\} + \left\{\right\} = \left\{\right\}$.

Thus, the correct expression for $\color{blue}S + \color{red}{S'}$ is:

$$\color{blue}S + \color{red}{S'} =
    \left\{
            \color{blue}S
            + \color{red}{\left\{ *1 \right\}}
    \right\}
    \cup
    \left\{
            \color{red}{S'}
            + \color{blue}{\left\{ *1, \left\{ *1 \right\}, *2 \right\}},
            \color{red}{S'}
            + \color{blue}{\left\{ *2, \left\{ *1, \left\{ *1 \right\}, *2 \right\} \right\}},
            \color{red}{S'}
            + \color{blue}{\left\{ \left\{ *1 \right\}, \left\{ \left\{ *1 \right\} \right\}, \left\{ *1, \left\{ *1 \right\}, *2 \right\} \right\}}
    \right\} $$